# The number of keypoints detected by SIFT is very low

Tags: opencv, sift, image-stitching

I have an image stitching code and SIFT was used to detect keypoints. When I use an image which is downloaded from internet the number of keypoints is very good. But when I use images which are taken by camera, the number of keypoints is very bad. This my code to detect keypoints. What can be problem?

```
> Ptr<SIFT> detector = SIFT::create(0,3,-1,5,2.6); //0,3,-1,5,0.6   
> std::vector <KeyPoint> kp1, kp2;    
> Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
> detector -> detectAndCompute (imageA, noArray(), kp1, descriptors1);    
> detector -> detectAndCompute (imageB, noArray(),kp2, descriptors2);    
> //Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = BFMatcher::create();    
> Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create(DescriptorMatcher::FLANNBASED);
```

Comment: you could try to change sift parameters. Probaby you can adjust the feature score threshold. Other possible ways: Normalize your image (scale min value to 0 and highest value to 255) or use histogram equalization. Can you show some of your images? keypoint detection/description only works well in textured scenes.

Comment: Why did you modify the default values of `SIFT::create()`. The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d5/d3c/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1SIFT.html) of the third value `contrastThreshold = 0.04` says "The larger the threshold, the less features are produced by the detector." You changed the value to -1. I don't even know if a negative value makes sense. I would at first try feature detection with the default values and maybe change one parameter after another to determine if I get better results. SIFT is very well balanced.